# How to implement Transformers for forecasting time series?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, huggingface-transformers, transformer-model

I need to implement Transformer in order to forecast multivariate time series. I found this [page](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tfm/nlp/layers/Transformer) from Tensorflow which explains what the Transformer contains, but it's not very clear to me how it should be implemented. I tried to implement it in the same way I would do with LSTM (inspired from YT), but it doesn't work like this and couldn't find inspiration on YT.

Here is my code:

Initial steps:

```
df = pd.read_csv('myfile.csv')

train_dates = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
cols = list(df[['A', 'B', 'C']])
df_for_training = df[cols].astype(float)
scaler = StandardScaler()
scaler.fit(df_for_training)
df_for_training_scaled = scaler.transform(df_for_training)
trainX = []  
trainY = []
n_future = 1
n_past = 14 
for i in range(n_past, len(df_for_training_scaled) - n_future + 1):
  trainX.append(df_for_training_scaled[i - n_past:i, 0:df_for_training.shape[1]])
  trainY.append(df_for_training_scaled[i + n_future - 1:i + n_future, 0])
trainX, trainY = np.array(trainX), np.array(trainY)
```

Important:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_addons as tfa
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout
from tensorflow_addons.layers import MultiHeadAttention, LayerNormalization

model = Sequential()
model.add(MultiHeadAttention(64, num_heads=4))
model.add(LayerNormalization())
model.add(MultiHeadAttention(32, num_heads=4))
model.add(LayerNormalization())
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(trainY.shape[1]))

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')
model.summary()

history = model.fit(trainX, trainY, epochs=2, batch_size=16, validation_split=0.1, verbose=1)
```

Could you please help me?

Comment: Have you looked at [this](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-io/blob/master/examples/timeseries/timeseries_classification_transformer.py)